# Powershell -like filter

Tags: powershell, expression

I am running command `alias | where Name -like "*invoke*"` but it does not return anything. Why this happens?

When I  run different command `alias | where Name -like "*tee*"` it will return result just fine.

Is this some problem with how -like expression is built?

Comment: Do you *have* any aliases that have a name containing the word "invoke"?

Comment: Yes, there is. It is pretty much default powershell list, there is wget -> Invoke-WebRequest et cetera.

Comment: But in that alias, the `Name` is just `wget`, it does not contain the word `invoke`. The *Definition*, however, does.

Comment: try this:  get-command *invoke*.  Then try get-alias *invoke*.

Comment: When I try it, there are several command with the letters invoke in them.  But none of them are aliases.

Comment: Check out the `ReferencedCommand` property instead of `Name`.

Comment: I can understand the confusion though, if you type in just `alias`, the `Name` column of the output actually says stuff like `tee -> Tee-Object`, but in that alias object, the Name still only contains "tee" and the Definition is the "Tee-Object".

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Definition` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.aliasinfo.definition?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0#System_Management_Automation_AliasInfo_Definition) instead of `Name`. `Name` property contains only alias name. For example in the case of `Format-Table`, `Name` property contains only `ft`

```
alias | where Definition -like '*invoke*'
```

Comment: Okay thank you, I think I found a way to do what I need with command `alias | where DisplayName -like "*invoke*"` However it is still unclear to me why Name does not work.

Comment: @JariYlilahti Name only contain alias name, Not the complete command name. For example, In the case of `Invoke-Command` command, `Name` contains `icm` and `Definition`(Or `DisplayName`) contain `Invoke-Command`

Comment: @JariYlilahti, the value in the `Name` column that is shown in the _formatted output_ also includes the alias' definition (e.g. `icm -> Invoke-Command`), but that is just for _display_ purposes. The underlying [`System.Management.Automation.AliasInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.AliasInfo) instance's `.Name` property (sensibly) contains _just_ the name (e.g. `icm`).

Comment: The confusion is probably stemming from the output of `alias`, which lists stuff like `tee -> Tee-Object` in the `Name` column, making it appear that the name actually contains all of that. It doesn't, however, and that column contains both the Name property value and the Definition property value.

Comment: The `DisplayName` property will also do